# Codeigniter MY_Controller: is it only possible to extend core once?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I have successfully extended the core using the MY_Controller as described in CI's documentation.

This way I can put some repetitive functions (ie, auth check) in the constructor of MY_Controller so they always run before methods from my other controllers.

My issue now is that some parts of my webapp are open (ie, don't require login) and others require login.

Therefore, I cannot extend ALL my controllers from MY_Controller (which contains an auth check function).

I wondered if it would be possible to extend the core so as to have, say, LOG_Controller and NOLOG_Controller.

Then, controllers that require login would extend from LOG_Controller --- and controllers that do not require login would extend from NOLOG_Controller.

Is this posssible? (or is it bad form?)

It seems config/config.php only allows for ***one*** core extension prefix so I'm not sure it's possible.

Let me know what you think or if there's a better way of doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at this article http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY - It is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: yes, this is exactly hat I was thinking about, thx for the ref

Comment: Looks clean but I couldn't get it working in my install. I'm probably on a different version

Comment: It's been 4 years and that site is working. Avoid just putting links and also accepting answers which contain links only.

Answer (score 8):

I use the following trick. Define all your base controllers in My_Controller.php:

```
<?php

class My_Controller extends CI_Controller{

}

class LOG_Controller extends My_Controller{

} 

class NOLOG_Controller extends My_Controller{

}
?>
```

This makes all defined controllers available later in your controllers. Just avoid making the base controllers too fat.

Also you can check this example: https://github.com/aquilax/novigeroi2/blob/master/application/core/AQX_Controller.php

Comment: @torr This is exactly what I do. It works like a charm. I have a little bit different use case. In my example I have MY_Controller do some basic stuff I need (like set layouts/templates). Then I have a "Secure_Controller" which inherits MY_Controller. From there I have different controllers for the various areas/sections of my site. Easily change authentication, layouts, and more. "Fat" controllers would affect performance somewhat, but I can't imagine you doing anything to crazy in these controllers. Just basic setting up stuff that you would have had to do anyways.

Comment: @torr MY_Controller.php is loaded on each request, that's why keeping it slim is a good idea.

Comment: tx aquilaX +1 for the concept - I selected as answer the one that links to a  nice guide from Phil Sturgeon on this - Phil says in the comments of that article that your approach works but may bloat unnecessarily if one is not careful in keeping the controller skinny

Comment: damn another thread suggested editing config file to load all core controllers, I was reluctant to do it and found this, this solution is awesome! And you can practically have n number of core controllers :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't posted any source code, let's imagine your `MY_Controller` looks similar to the following example:

File path: **application/core/MY_Controller.php**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        if ( !$this->ion_auth->logged_in() ) {
            redirect('auth/login');
        }
    }
}
```

Your "protected" controllers extend this one and inherit it's methods, as follows:

File path: **application/controllers/Secure.php**

```
class Secure extends MY_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

You want to allow both *some* protected and *some* unprotected controllers in your application. In order for you to keep those controllers protected, they must extend `MY_Controller` and inherit it's `__construct()` method. For any controller that doesn't need to inherit that `__construct()` method, you simply extend the `CI_Controller` directly, as follows:

File path: **application/controllers/Insecure.php**

```
class Insecure extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

There you have it. Controllers which inherit directly from (*extend*) the `CI_Controller` will be "insecure".

### One Consideration

The main consideration here is that you may have additional methods in your controller that you want to pass to **all** your controllers - in which case this may not be the best solution for you. If that *is* the case, you can always move those methods to a **helper** instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible. There are ways of doing what you need extending the same controller. Why not put all your open pages in a folder (like Public) and check in MY_Controller if the request is directed to that folder. If not, requires auth.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy solution is to simply require the additional classes/controllers you need at the bottom of your application/controller/my_controller.php file

My custom controller looks like this, didn't require any additional configuration settings:

```
class My_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    // do something clever here

}

// do something even more clever here ...
require_once("application/core/tool_controller.php");
```

Seems pretty dry to me and then allows you to customize your application by setting up a templates / layouts controller directory somewhere. I'm just finishing up an older CI project so I'm taking it further but I'm sure you could also play around with some config variables elsewhere to make it even DRY-er